# Query PostgreSQL table if entry exists, add if not

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to populate a PostgreSQL table with some static data (names which will later be used as a reference by my program), but my code is doing the opposite of what I expect.

In summary, my question is how can I query table for the existence of a `User` object with id equal to `user`, and if not, add it?

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
# ...plus other configurations parameters

if not DBSession.query(User.id==user):
    print "Adding a new entry."
    DBSession.add(User(**user))
elif DBSession.query(User.id==user):
    print "Entry already exists."
```

Where `User` is an object with multiple attributes, and `user` is an instance of that object with certain values for those attributes.

However, regardless of whether or not the name is in the table, I always fall into the elif clause. I suspect this is because the if/elif logic is treating the presence of a query as a Boolean, rather than using the result of that query. Fair enough, I guess this is not a valid approach.

I have also attempted to use the more explicit `exists()` method, but I have the same issue (the query appears to be treated as a Boolean instead of being executed and returning the result).

```
q = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.id==user)
if not DBSession.query(q.exists()):
    print "Adding a new entry."
    DBSession.add(User(**user))
else:
    print "Entry already exists.
```

Unfortunately, printing `DBSession.query(User.id==user)` simply returns `SELECT user.id = %(id_1)s AS anon_1` which is not very informative (just the SQL query constructed by SQLAlchemy). I tried to explicitly `execute()` this SQL query, but was unsuccessful, and I wonder if it is even necessary to explicitly do so.

Executing a query explicitly...

```
q = DBSession.query(User.id==user)
DBSession.execute(q)
```

... returns the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError)
can't adapt type 'dict' [SQL: 'SELECT user.id = %(id_1)s AS anon_1 \nFROM user'] 
[parameters: {'id_1': {'first_name': u'Spike', 'last_name': u'Lee'}}]
```

I now understand that `anon_1` is an alias used as a handle for the query result, and `%(id_1)s` above was simply a variable.

I also tried the `where()` method and got the same ProgrammingError as above.

```
DBSession.query(exists().where(User.id==user)).scalar()
```

PS: I'm using Postgres 9.3 under SQLAlchemy 1.1.6 with Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 16.04.

**Temporary solution**

I can count the number of matching occurences in the table (and add the entry if the count is 0), but would prefer to use `exists()` as it will be more efficient to stop at the first matching entry rather than counting through the whole table (my entries are unique anyway).

```
q = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.first_name == user['first_name']).count()
if q == 0:
    DBSession.add(User(**user))
```

Comment: Just a small comment re "it will be more efficient to stop at the first matching entry" - you can use `.limit(1)` just before the `.count()` to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `limit(1)` returns new `Query` object, not `User`. You can use `.first()` instead of `limit`, `count` and any other. Like this: `if DBSession.query(User).filter(User.first_name == user['first_name']).first(): # do if exist`